# A word for being in between 2 opinions?

Tags: single-word-requests

My main language is Dutch and I was wondering if there is a word for being in between 2 opinions.

Let me give you an example:

- I am against lowering the drinking age, but at the same time not really as long as its being used responsible.

It's a bit of yes and no.

Hope you guys can help me out and teach me (and hopefully others) something.

Comment: try **ambivalent** or **equivocal**.

Comment: You might be *[vacillating](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/vacillate)* (or, more colloquially, *waffling*).

Comment: You're ***on the fence***.

Comment: @LeeLeon While *ambivalent* is used frequently in everyday English, *equivocal* isn't, at least in my dialect (Canadian English) (*unequivocal* is, though, for some reason).

Answer (score 1):

I'm stuck with **a dilemma** when I consider the pros and cons of lowering the drinking age.

[**dilemma**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dilemma) a problem involving a difficult choice.

[**1.**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dilemma) "the dilemma of "liberty versus order" —J. M. Burns

[**2.**](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/dilemma) "She was placed in the dilemma of running all risks headlong on the next day, or of pausing for a future opportunity which might never occur."

[**3.**](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=hXZPAwAAQBAJ&pg=PT576&dq=%22a+dilemma%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj0nYap--bZAhUNmJAKHRxKDQA4tAEQ6AEIKDAA) "In Sophie's Choice, Sophie faced a dilemma in which she had to choose which of her two children would live, or let both be killed by the Nazis."

p.s. **"on the fence"**, as suggested by Dan Bron, fits better because it refers solely to not being able to chose between A or B.  A "dilemma" would be more appropriate if you really had to make a choice, like Sophie.

Answer (score 0):

**hedge**  [dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/hedge?s=t)

an act or means of preventing complete loss of a bet, *an argument*, an investment, or the like, with a partially counterbalancing or qualifying one.

> I am against lowering the drinking age, but to **hedge**, not really
>   as long as its being used responsible.

Answer (score 0):

The word conflicted would apply.  [Conflict](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/conflict) at OED

> **Conflicted** means A state of mind in which a person experiences a clash
>   of opposing feelings or needs.